# Net Core / Angular CORS error on some Api calls but not others

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core

I have a Angular app that calls two different POST API methods. On my staging env I notice one would be correct and add a access-control-allow-origin: * in the Response headers but the other one doesn't and I find it really odd.

So technically one API call works and one doesn't when hosted on staging. They do the same thing where they just fetch a list of data

CORS in my startup file

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

in different part

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

and both controllers extend a basecontroller

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public abstract class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: Are you able to call the API by other means such as from Postman?

Comment: Is the second call a GET? Are they both in a controller inheriting BaseApiController? If you inspect the answser via Fiddler or Postman, is the response what you expect (except the CORS header of course)? Do both calls require authentication?

Comment: Both are POST requests. both require authentication and both work locally and give me all my response headers back for CORS. I am using Cloudflare for security and hosting my DNS but then it still doesn't explain why one works and the other doesn't as they are pretty much identical

Comment: I will try via Postman when I am on the PC again.

Comment: It's possible something happens before reaching the CORS middleware? Have you got another middleware before the CORS one? Maybe the server itself is sending back a response without reaching the application. The Postman call + the logs should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks I will try Postman with logs later and let you know my findings

Comment: I had the same problem. If an error occurred while processing the request, the CORS information would no longer be added to the response header.

Comment: How did you find the error? using postman? locally it processes without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a Simple Update of the database was required. The CORS issue through me off wildly but it all works fine after updating the database

Comment: The database call was failing? Was the database call in a middleware before the CORS one?

Comment: No automatic migrations for EF was enabled thus my staging DB never got updated.